# One to many relation : child is flagged Modified instead Deleted

Tags: entity-framework-core

I have some troubles using One to Many relationships with EntityFramework Core. When I delete a child object in the List property on the parent, this Child object is flagged as Modified by the ChangeTracker (and not Deleted). However, when I call SaveChanges on the context, this entity is well Deleted.

Of course, I could force the flag of the entity to Deleted but, I would prefer another solution because I'm using AutoMapper to update my entities. and I don't want to mix the AutoMapper mapping process and EntityFramework Context.

```cs
var parent = new Parent();

var child = new Child();
parent.Childs.Add(child);
await context.SaveChangesAsync();

// removing the first child
parent.Childs.RemoveAt(0);  

// fails (Expected Deleted, got Modified)
Assert.Equal(EntityState.Deleted, context.Entry(child).State);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best explanation of this behavior is contained inside one of the expected breaking changes in EF Core 3.0 - [Cascade deletions now happen immediately by default](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-3.0/breaking-changes#cascade-deletions-now-happen-immediately-by-default):

> **Old behavior**
>
> Before 3.0, EF Core applied cascading actions (deleting dependent entities when a required principal is deleted or when the relationship to a required principal is severed) did not happen until `SaveChanges` was called.
>
> **New behavior**
>
> Starting with 3.0, EF Core applies cascading actions as soon as the triggering condition is detected. For example, calling `context.Remove()` to delete a principal entity will result in all tracked related required dependents also being set to Deleted immediately.
>
> **Why**
>
> This change was made to improve the experience for data binding and auditing scenarios where it is important to understand which entities will be deleted before `SaveChanges` is called.

The first section explains the current behavior and the last section explains why they are changing it - to help usage scenarios like yours.

With that being said, you should either apply the cascade option manually, or wait for EF Core 3.0 if you can afford that.